# Constructing an $R$-algebra from an $R$-module, and their relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then every $r \in R$ could be seen as a group endomorphism on $M$, i.e. we have a natural map $f : R \to \operatorname{End}(M)$. This map is a ring homomorphism, and so by setting $r\cdot \varphi := f(r)\varphi$ for $\varphi \in \operatorname{End}(M)$ we have an action of $R$ on $\operatorname{End}(M)$, which gives us an $R$-algebra.

Is there anything known about the relation of this $R$-algebra to the module $M$, some theorems relating those two?

Comment: Yes, of course, one is the endomorphism ring of the other. There are tons and tons of results relating endomorphism rings and their moduls, if one has property A then the other has property B, and many of these can be found in most Algebra textbooks. Could you thus maybe clarify what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @DirkLiebhold Sorry, I do not know of any results. Would you mind citing one? The relation here is between the module and an associated algebra, so not directly the endormorphism ring itself...

Comment: In many cases, $f$ will be injective. In this cases, you don't have to worry about the difference between endomorphism ring and algebra. The cases where $f$ is not injective get a little bit more complicated, yes, but I'm sure there are still nice results for that one (I just don't have an algebra textbook at hand right now to look them up).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> we have an action of $R$ on $\operatorname{End}(M)$, which gives us an $R$-algebra.

No, not quite. To make $End(M)$ an $R$ algebra, the map $f$ would have to map into the **center** of $End(M)$.

For example, $\mathbb H$ is a $\mathbb C$ module, and has such a map, but there is no map of $\mathbb C$ into the center of $\mathbb H$. $\mathbb H$ is *not* a $\mathbb C$ algebra.

The map $f$ you are talking about is a well-known equivalent way of defining what it means to be an $R$ module. You can either specify all the axioms about how the addition and multiplication works, or you can say "a ring homomorphism from $R$ into $End(M_\mathbb Z)$."

As for your last question, let me say this. There is not such a tight connection between $M_R$ and $End(M_\mathbb Z)$, other than the property we mentioned that $End(M_\mathbb Z)$ contains a homomorphic image of $R$.

The really interesting relationship is between $M_R$ and $End(M_R)$. You can say *lots* of things about that relationship. For example, the direct summands of $M_R$ correspond to idempotent elements of $End(M_R)$.

Every once in a while, some structure in $M_R$ can tell you a lot about the structure of $End(M_R)$. For example, if $M_R$ is simple, $End(M_R)$ is a division ring; if $M_R$ is semisimple, then $End(M_R)$ is von Neumann regular; if the submodules of $M_R$ are linearly ordered, then $End(M_R)$ has either one or two maximal right ideals.

Those are just the ones off the top of my head... to be sure there are more.